# ionic 2 looking for app.ts when it should be looking for app.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I am moving an `ionic 2 Beta 6` app over to `ionic 2 Beta 9`. I am doing this by creating a new `ionic 2 --v2 starter` app and then copying over my app .js and .html source files (having made all of the changes needed to update to Beta 9) to the app directory in the starter app folder.

When I run ionic serve it complains:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/billnoble/Documents/veeu-app2/app/app.ts'

My source files are not typescript so I have changed the ionic.config.json file to:

```
{
  "name": "VeeU",
  "app_id": "375dc139",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": false
}
```

What do I have to do to get ionic to use javascript rather than typescript files?

I created the starter app with `ionic start starterapp --v2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a javascript starter app with ionic 2 rather than a typescipt app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950594/create-a-javascript-starter-app-with-ionic-2-rather-than-a-typescipt-app)

Answer (score 0):

You should create the starter app with:

```
ionic start xxx --v2 --no-ts
```

And then copy your app .js and .html source files in that project.

Comment: Unfortunately that still creates a Typescript app.