# Create a javascript starter app with ionic 2 rather than a typescript app

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to create a JS starter project but `ionic start xxx --v2` creates a typescript project.

I need to create a JS starter project so I can copy across an existing JS ionic 2 app to a clean installation.

I did try renaming all of my JS files to typescript  but a get a shed load of error messages of the type:

> Property xxx does not exist on type yyy

Answer (score 11):

Just like you can read in [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/):

> Ionic 2 applications are created as TypeScript by default.
>
> Want to use JavaScript instead? Pass the `--no-ts` flag and get a
>   project set up for JavaScript instead.

So you would need to run

`ionic start xxx --v2 --no-ts`

==============================

**EDIT:**

You're right. It seems to be a bug either in the documentation or in the Ionic CLI. In this [commit](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/commit/3f87bfb09e37214301c27863c53bb7a9cabdf555) you can see the title is *remove javascript as an option for v2 projects ...* and [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1057) in the last comment they mention something about updating the docs (because it says *Want to use JavaScript instead? Pass the --no-ts flag and get a project set up for JavaScript instead.*).

You can follow along this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/typescript-project-files-named-js/54674/13) to see if someone from Ionic Team answer about this issue.

=============================

**EDIT 2:**

Just asked in `ionic-v2` Slack channel and the answer was:

> We're going all in on TS.
>
> You could do your own work and covert it toa es6 workflow, but we want people to use typescript

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It still creates a Typescript app with .ts files.

Comment: In the "Edit 2" @sebaferreras adds that it is not possible to create an Ionic2 app without TypeScript & quotes the Ionic2 team "going all in on TS" - which is disappointing from the Ionic team :(

Comment: Jeez that's pretty harsh when u want to port something in javascript from web to mobile.

Comment: TypeScript is a niche community compared to JavaScript .. it's a big mistake in my opinion to shun those who don't like waiting for transpilers and prefer JavaScript - As a result, many of us are all looking for a way to use Ionic without using TypeScript .. That should tell you something

Answer (score 4):

Here is the official answer from Ionic Team:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/typescript-project-files-named-js/54674/16

No support for JS anymore. Only Typescript