# Ionic v2 sample with javascript

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I could not find a way to start Ionic v2 sample app `ionic start appname --v2` with JavaScript and **NOT** TypeScript.

I have tried `--v2 --js`, `--v2 --no-ts`and I always get ts version of app.

Am I wrong or JavaScript version is not available any longer in sample start app?! =>  [ionic-cli](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/commit/3f87bfb09e37214301c27863c53bb7a9cabdf555#diff-26488b21857121cfbc2862f3af3b0a3cL51).

It seems weird.

Any idea to get it to work? Thank you for your help

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950594/create-a-javascript-starter-app-with-ionic-2-rather-than-a-typescipt-app/37950878#37950878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950594/create-a-javascript-starter-app-with-ionic-2-rather-than-a-typescipt-app/37950878#37950878):

> Just asked in ionic-v2 Slack channel and the answer was:
>
> > We're going all in on TS.
> >
> > You could do your own work and covert it toa es6 workflow, but we want
> >     people to use typescript

As [@HerbiShtini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976820/herbishtini) mentioned in the comments, in [this issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1057) it's said that:

> Ionic2 applications are only available as Typescript.

Comment: I will just copy the framework(js, scss) and get out of their ecosystem then. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the bad news... But why don't you give Typescript a try? After all, Angular2 has been written in Typescript.

Comment: They must have a reason for doing that. I am a bit in hurry and did not want to spend time with TS but I will give it an overview. Thanks

Comment: This clears doubts even further =>  https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1057

Comment: If you don't mind, please feel free to edit the answer to include that information or tell me to do so and I will :)