# Ionic 2 in pure JS (No Transpile. No TS. No more waiting for debug)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, transpiler

I'm a Ionic v1 developer and since the launch of Ionic 2 I've started to be excited with the features and performance. But the TS approach is not my side.
I decided to learn Angular 2 following [the ES methods](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html#!#class-metadata) and everything ok. But trying to  move Ionic TS to ES manually (seeing that the --no-ts option is [no more available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950594/create-a-javascript-starter-app-with-ionic-2-rather-than-a-typescipt-app)), some bugs started to appear on my console, breaking all the ES method. I need help from some Ionic 2/Angular 2 and transpiler specialists to develop this solution (for me and for the ES lovers).

The error that appears in console is:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for provideLocationStrategy: (PlatformLocation, ?, Config).
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:47002:21)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getFactoryMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:46907:28)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:47097:45)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:47042:47
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:47026:21)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:46736:65
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:46727:51)
at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleMetadata (http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/lib.js:46692:31)
```

The supposed code that fires the bug:

```
(function (app) {
app.AppModule =
    ng.core.NgModule({
        imports: [
            ionicBundle.IonicModule.forRoot(app.MyApp)
        ],
        declarations: [
            app.MyApp,
            app.AboutPage,
            app.ContactPage,
            app.HomePage,
            app.TabsPage
        ],
        bootstrap: [ionicBundle.IonicApp],
        entryComponents: [
            app.MyApp,
            app.AboutPage,
            app.ContactPage,
            app.HomePage,
            app.TabsPage
        ]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function AppModule () {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

[Here](https://github.com/menosprezzi/ionic-v2-es) is my repo with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using npm 2, try updating to npm 3 and latest node.

Comment: for latest you mean Node 6.x or Node 7.x?